# Restore deleted git file that had some changes

Tags: git

I made some changed to a file and by mistake deleted that file. I have not yet committed those changes. I want to undelete that file but keep the changes that I made. How do I do that using git?

Comment: Commit early and often. You can always change (well... replace) them later.

Comment: If you deleted the file straight (without running `git rm`) and you had added the file to index with your changes, the file is still in the index, at least. If that's the case, then commit as soon as possible so that you don't lose them. Then you can go back to the previous revision so that you can continue working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using git, unfortunately you can't, since the changes were never commited.

The alternative you could hope for is to check, if any, the local history of changes in the editor you happen to work with.